# How does one implement flood fill in a 2D array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia, flood-fill

## The problem

Suppose I have a 2D matrix, with some random integers being either a `0` or a `1`. How do I flood-fill a continuous region in my array?

This algorithm can especially be used in image processing to fill a color with another color in an enclosed region like the paint-bucket tool.

## Example

Suppose my array is:

```
1 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

I want to fill the region of `1`s in the top-right corner with something else like an `8`. How do I implement this? I know the indices of any `1` in that region, and I have the indices of any one of the `1`s.

After filling with `8`s, the array should look like this:

```
1 0 8 8 8 8 0
0 0 8 8 8 8 8
0 0 0 8 8 8 8
0 1 0 0 0 8 8
0 0 0 8 8 8 8
```

## My efforts:

I have tried the following methods:

- Going through each item in the array, checking if it is a `1`, replacing it with an `8`. Clearly this didn’t work since it simply replaced all the `1`s with `8`s. Even the `1`s outside the region were converted to `8`s.
- Using relative coordinates, checking for `1`s, and replacing with `8`s for the initial indices we are given. In short, replacing all neighbors whose values are `1` with an `8`. This also did not work since it only replaced the nearest 8 neighbors and did not fill the region as I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voila! The answer lied in recursion:

The function takes in your array as `arr`, and the coordinates (or indices) of the `1` you know in the form of a tuple `(x, y)` as arguments.

When using relative coordinates, we call the flood_fill function on each of them:

```
function flood_fill(arr, (x, y))
    # check every element in the neighborhood of the element at (x, y) in arr
    for x_off in -1:1
        for y_off in -1:1
            # put the next part in a try-catch block so that if any index
            # is outside the array, we move on to the next element.
            try
                # if the element is a 1, change it to an 8 and call flood_fill 
                # on it so it fills it's neighbors
                if arr[x + x_off, y + y_off] == 1
                    arr[x + x_off, y + y_off] = 8
                    flood_fill(arr, (x + x_off, y + y_off))
                end
            catch
                continue
            end
        end
    end
end
```